# How to remove byte code of deployed smart contract which was deployed using Ropsten Test Network?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, ropsten, bytecode

I 've deployed my smart contract on Etherscan using **Ropsten** Test network. I can see there is bytecode for my deployed contract on **ropsten etherscan**. I want to hide or **don't want to show** the **bytecode** for my contract.
Is it possible? If **Yes** then **What should I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible because the bytecode's public availability doens't depend on etherscan, it depends on the chain itself. On Ethereum, everything is public.